# What replaces SecurityTokenCache in .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, wif

When WIF was separate, you could create SessionSecurityTokenHandler and specify a token cache for use in something like a web farm scenario. Now, SessionSecurityTokenHandler in .NET 4.5 doesn't have that constructor parameter. Is there something equivalent in .NET 4.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the replacement. It is documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.sessionsecuritytokencache.aspx